# Placement of the auxiliary verb within a sentence

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, do

When using **do** as auxiliary verb for emphasis, could one swap it around in a sentence or **not**?

For example,

> Do please check the details beforehand.

> Please do check the details beforehand.

Are both these versions correct? What is the difference between their meanings, if any?

Also, should it be **not** or **no** above?

Comment: Please check, or, please do check sound fine.  Bringing it at the start is like "He is heartily eating", becoming something like "Is heartily he eating"

Comment: They are both fine: the adverb "please" can occur before or after auxiliary "do". It should be "not".

Comment: @BillJ— Thanks. May I know what exactly is the problem with using **no** instead?

Comment: Note that both examples of using *do* are not wrong, but stuffy. **No** does not work because it implies **no swap** it around. Even in my first sentence, you would not want **no wrong**.

Comment: _No_ is wrong in the first sentence, and _not_ is right because _no_ doesn't occur in the negation of the original sentence, viz _could one swap it around in a sentence or could one not swap it around in a sentence?_ Sluicing the second clause leaves _not_ sitting high and dry. Not _no_.

Answer (score 0):

BillJ commented:

> They are both fine: the adverb "please" can occur before or after auxiliary "do". It should be "not".